# Set up C++ Intellisense for VSCode in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I would like to know how to set up Intellisense for VSCode in Ubuntu.  I'm new to VSCode and fairly new to cpp and Ubuntu.  I've seen this question asked a few times here and I haven't seen an answer posted.  I'm in Ubuntu 16.04 and working with ROS (Lunar), using catkin_make (a cmake extension).

I've tried to follow the [examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/Getting%20started%20with%20IntelliSense%20configuration.md) given on git hub. First I tried to create a compile_commands.json file, but I can't find any information on how to do this.  I tried the ccmake gui and cmake-qt-gui neither had this option.  I tried adding set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS true) to the CMakeLists.txt. These efforts seem to have broken my workspace.

At this point, I gave up on the preferred solution and decided to try manually editing the includePaths in c_cpp_properties.json.  This worked a couple days ago, but now it does nothing (still cannot resolve the header files in the include directory) and VSCode seems to delete the includePaths I add about 5s after I re-open the workspace.  I've looked for an example c_cpp_properties.json to copy but they all seem to be for windows.

Edit:

It seems to not be able to resolve the directory structure.  When I place the .h files in the same directory as the .cpp it can find them but when they are are in the include folder it fails. This set up fails to resolve pylon_camera_node.h: [Screen shot of settings and directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmaL5.png)

Edit 2:

By disabling some of my extensions (C++ Intellisens and CMake Tools Helper), I was able to fix the overwriting of c_cpp_properties.json.  I noticed other users were adding the same paths to the "browse" "path" section and "includePath", once I did that my manual edits started working ([example of working c_cpp_properties.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlF8Q.png)).  This is still not ideal because I have to manually find header files, but bash locate is making that manageable.

Edit 3:

My includes were still underlined with a green squiggle, adding the following to settings.json seemed to fix this:

```
"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser",
```

It seems to allow IntelliSense to provide fuzzy results.

If anyone knows a way to more automatically resolve this (perhaps by generating compile_commands.json) I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I also tried setting up the C++ Intellisense extension, first installing Gnu Global, but it doesn't seem to recognize 'codegnuglobal.executable' in the settings file.

Comment: Why don't you just install the C++ [Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)?

Comment: I've installed that and a few others: C/C++, C++ Intellisense, CMake, CMake Tools, CMake Tools Helper (might be what is overwriting include paths), ROS, Msg Language Support, XML.   Going to disable C++ Intellisense and CMake Tools Helper and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I now believe many of my issues came from using the cmake-gui to configure the workspace instead of catkin_make.  I made one other mistake the correct CMake command to generate compiler_commands.json is:

`set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS)`

After rebuilding the catkin workspace and entering this line in the package level CMake file I was able to generate compiler_commands.json in the build directory.

One last point of note, with ROS compiler_commands.json is often not the full picture, you may need to add "catkin_ws/devel/include" for any autogenerated msg code for example.